# Добавление дополнительных полей в валидацию

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, валидация

Делаю запрос для получения доступных способов оплаты.
Для некоторых приходят доп. поля. К примеру, для QIWI - номер телефона.
Не знаю как такое поле ввести под валидацию.

Код обработки результата:

```
<div id="payments">
    <div payments-directive ng-repeat="payment in payments track by $index">
        <span id="a2dCheckBox{{ payments[$index].id }}" data-discount="{{ payments[$index].discount }}" ng-click="setPayment(payment)"></span>
        <img width="32" alt="{{ payments[$index].name }}" src="{{ payments[$index].icon }}">
        <label>{{ payments[$index].name }}</label>
        <span ng-if="payments[$index].discount>0">{{ payments[$index].extra }}</span>
        <div
            ng-if="payments[$index].addFields.length>0"
            ng-bind-html="getHtmlContent(payments[$index].addFields)"
            id="payDesc{{ payments[$index].id }}"
        >addFields</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пробую хотя бы значение присвоить:

```
$scope.getPayments = function() {
    if ($scope.form.$valid ) {
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            data: {},
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.payments = data.payments;    
            $scope.showQIWI = true;
            $scope.payment.qiwi = '9876543210';
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.payment.qiwi = '9876543210';
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Но бесполезно.

`addFields` с сервера для QIWI:

```
<b>+7&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><input 
    type="text" name="phone_for_qiwi" class="field_text" id="phone_for_qiwi" value="" 
    ng-show="showQIWI" show-valid 
    ng-model="payment.qiwi" 
    ng-click="alertQIWI()" 
>
<br/>
QIWI - Электронная платёжная система. Оплата в терминалах и через QIWI Кошелек.
```

Вообще ничего не работает: ни `ng-click`, ни значение не присваивается, ни валидация.

**UPD1:**
`console.log(payment.qiwi)` показывает значение, но `ng-model="payment.qiwi"` не подхватывает его.

**UPD2:**
Прошу прощения:

```
console.log(payment.qiwi) => console.log($scope.payment.qiwi)
```

**UPD3:**
Сейчас:

```
$scope.getHtmlContent = function(html){
    var _html = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    return _html;
};
```

Если сделать так:

```
$scope.getHtmlContent = function(html){
    var _html = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    var $html = $compile(_html);
    return $html;
};
```

То получаю:

```
function (b,c,d){Sb(b,"scope");d=d||{};var e=d.parentBoundTranscludeFn,h=d.transcludeControllers;d=d.futureParentElement;e&&e.$$boundTransclude&&(e=e.$$boundTransclude);g||(g=(d=d&&d[0])?"foreignobject"!==ua(d)&&d.toString().match(/SVG/)?"svg":"html":"html");d="html"!==g?A(Yb(g,A("
").append(a).html())):c?Pa.clone.call(a):a;if(h)for(var l in h)d.data("$"+l+"Controller",h[l].instance);S.$$addScopeInfo(d,b);c&&c(d,b);f&&f(b,d,d,e);return d}
```

Comment: В функции getHtmlContent что у Вас происходит? Запрос на сервер? И что возвращает? promise? Попробуйте использовать для ng-bind-html переменную, значение ей присваивать в success-функции запроса html-темплейта.

Comment: @workres  
  
`
$scope.getHtmlContent = function(html){  
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);  
};
 `
  \n
` 
ng-bind-html="getHtmlContent(payments[$index].addFields)"
`

Я пытаюсь из строки построить HTML

addFields с сервера для QIWI привел в вопросе

Comment: Ясно, может может так попробовать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459194/angularjs-using-sce-trustashtml-with-ng-repeat , как в правильном ответе? showQIWI == true?

Comment: По ссылки вариант не помог. Сори забыл, добавил, но у меня было и есть сразу после получения ответа с сервера:
$scope.showQIWI = true;

Comment: Выложил код, вдруг поможет прояснить: http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/8vb92s98/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `$compile`.

**Обновление**

Создайте директиву вместо `ng-bind-html`. Она должна вставлять в текущий элемент новый, типа `angular.element(elem).append(_html)`. После этого: `$compile(elem)(scope);`. Это скомпилирует новый элемент в `scope`.

Comment: по возможности, пишите, пожалуйста, более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Пробовал UPD3 - так?

Comment: Нет, не так. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Сделал так: http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/8vb92s98/1/   :::   
Ругаетцо: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=form&p1=showValid   :::   
Делал require, не помогло, предположительно директива не верна.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря ответам @ne3Vubeki, получаем следующее:

```
<div id="payments">
    <div class="tl mb20" payments-directive ng-repeat="payment in payments track by $index">
        <span id="a2dCheckBox{{ payments[$index].id }}" data-discount="{{ payments[$index].discount }}" ng-click="setPayment(payment)" class="a2dCheckBox alignMiddle anime mr30"></span>
        <img width="32" alt="{{ payments[$index].name }}" src="{{ payments[$index].icon }}">
        <label class="cGrey ml10"><span ng-bind="payments[$index].name"></span></label>
        <span class="red ml10" ng-if="payments[$index].discount>0"><span ng-bind="payments[$index].extra"></span></span>
        <div
            id="payDesc{{ payments[$index].id }}" class="payDesc" style="display:block;"
            add-fields="{{ payment.addFields }}"
            >
            addFields
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

По сути ни чего нового - заменил директиву.

Код новой директивы addFields:

```
app.directive('addFields', function($compile){
    var odd = {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var template = "<div>"+attrs.addFields+"</div>";
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
    };
    return odd;
});
```

**ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО!**

> Нужно что бы в коде был хоть один тег.
>   Я просто обернул в DIV.
>   Иначе система ругаетца на контент, ждет HTML.

**UPD1:**
Поля компилируются, но как то не до конца оно завелось: работал `ng-click`, но не отрабатывала прописанная директива `show-valid`, причем я мог задать `true/false` переменным в директиве `ng-show`.
В общем [схожая проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882506/form-validation-and-fields-added-with-compile) у братьев по духу.
Итого директиву можно переписать так:

```
app.directive('addFields', function($compile){
    var odd = {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var template = "<div>"+attrs.addFields+"</div>";
            var result = $(template).appendTo(element);
            $compile(result)($scope);
        }
    };
    return odd;
});
```

Подмечу: *Ребята тоже перед компиляцией оборачивают в `div`*.
**И еще запомни!**

> Firstly include in the DOM, then compile